# same instance of uiwebview in two viewController swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, singleton

here is my situation

I have this setup,

```
UIWebView webView

ViewControllerA {
  IBOutlet weak var webView : UIWebView
  override viewDidLoad { 
    doSomething()
  } 
}

ViewControllerB {
  IBOutlet weak var webView : UIWebView (different instance! wrong)
  override viewDidLoad { 
    doSomethingDifferent()
  } 
}
```

I use Tab Bar controller to move from viewA to viewB
and I want to move my webView from viewA to viewB so I can show the exact same web page with different information at the bottom of the view depending if im in viewA or viewB

since the webview could play a video, I want this video to be playing in both views at the same time so I can't reload the webView, just move it.

Any ideas to achieve that? Already tried container views but it s'till two different instances of the UIWebView... is it possible to do it in interface builder or in swift?

Comment: Maybe your `UIWebView` should be implemented as some kind of shared instance. Maybe as a singleton. Or maybe it will work if you use a global variable. Although I think global variables are considered bad practice.

Comment: In such case you would have to load your UIWebView programatically. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Just a small warning -> you probably don't want to be using UIWebViews as they leak memory like crazy. Instead, take a look at WKWebview, gives you the exact same functionality without the memory issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is unsafe due to force unwrapping, but you can use it as a reference. I've declared `globalWebView` as a global variable.

First view controller:

```
var globalWebView: UIWebView?

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        globalWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 30, 300, 300))
        globalWebView?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/XLpDiIVX0Wo")!))
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.addSubview(globalWebView!)
    }
}
```

Second view controller:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.addSubview(globalWebView!)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works great with a global variable, `globalWebView = UIWebView(frame: parentFrame.bounds)` to get the exact size and position of my container view in storyboard, thanks!